# How can I keep filter in cookie via ag-grid?

Tags: angular, angular-material, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to keep ag-grid filter in cookie? If user filter something, it should be keep filter condition even if page is reloaded or user logout/login in ag-grid. How can i do that?

Comment: Use ag-grid's `getFilterModel`/`setFilterModel`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

may be local storage can help, than a cookie, use it together with getColumnState() of the ag-grid

```
localStorage.setItem('my-var', 'value');
var value= localStorage.getItem('my-var');
```

[mozilla: localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

[ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/)